# in which case we use '%' as coordinate of point in svg?

Tags: html, svg

I found using percentage (%) instead of numerical coordinate more efficient. But it seems it does not support points coordinate in case of path or polygon.

As shown in the code below, the rectangle is created using '%' the points of polygon.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <polygon points="'50%','10%' '10%','90%' '90%','80%'" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
<rect width="90%" height="90%" x= "10%" style="fill:violet; stroke: red; fill-opacity: 0.5"/>
</svg>
```

it should be like this

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <polygon points="50,10 10,90 90,80" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
<rect width="90%" height="90%" x= "10%" style="fill:violet; stroke: red; fill-opacity: 0.5"/>
</svg>
```

which works normally.
Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a viewBox then you don't need percentages because raw numbers behave like percentages. I.e. once you set viewBox="0 0 100 100", 50 means 50%.

like so...

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="50,10 10,90 90,80" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
<rect width="90" height="90" x="10" style="fill:violet; stroke: red; fill-opacity: 0.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've found exactly the same answer. Thanks anyway!